# Adding items to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary in python. To be more specific I want to read the input from the keyboard and then add it to dictionary. I am new to python and I don't know how can this be achieved.

```
 for i in range(3)

     key=input("Give key\n")
     name=input("Give name\n")
     #add these values in a dictionary
```

Comment: Please note that if using Python 2.x, you want `raw_input()`, _not_ `input()`.

Comment: Don't forget the colon (`:` symbol) after the `for` loop.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thx I will keep it in mind

Comment: @Hidde yeah you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first create empty dict:

```
d = {}
```

and then set values:

```
for i in range(3)
     key=input("Give key\n") # use raw_input in python 2x
     name=input("Give name\n")
     d[key] = name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with

```
myDict = dict()
```

Set a value in it by

```
myDict[myKey] = 'myValue'
```

Read a value from it with

```
myDict[myKey] #Result: 'myValue'
```

Check whether a key exists in a dictionary with

```
myKey in myDict #Evaluates to a bool
```

---

For your problem:

- Create a dictionary outside your loop
- Add each entered value at the desired index as I showed you above.